# I have integrated stripe connect payment process. I charge admin account its working fine but connect account returned insufficient balance error

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment

I have integrated stripe connect payment process. I charge admin account its working fine but connect account returned insufficient balance error

```
$payableAmount = $payableAmount * 100;

//Stripe admin account charge process

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      "amount" => 100, // $15.00 this time
      "currency" => 'GBP',
      "customer" => $stripeDetails['stripe_customer_id']
));

//charge working fine (In Dashboard currency converted GBP to UD)

$splitAmount = 100 * 2 / 100;
$splitAmount = 90 - $splitAmount;

$transfer = \Stripe\Transfer::create(array(
    'amount' => $splitAmount * 100,
    'currency' => 'GBP',
    'destination' => $storeData['stripe_account_id']
));

//transfer return Insufficient funds in Stripe account. In test mode, you can add funds to your available balance.
```

Comment: So you've charged for 100, but are trying to transfer 8800?

Comment: No I have charged 100 GBP Only for admin account thats working fine.Them I will check in admin dashboard the money currency is GBP to USD . Then transfer process same like I am using GBP currency It return insufficient  balance.. could you clear this problem. Help me.. what I did mistakes in the above code..

Comment: It's simple, you don't have 8800 in the account to transfer, since you're only charging 100 at a time. You'd have to run that script at least 88 times for the account to have enough funds.

Answer (score 1):

You've charged the customer £1 GBP, Stripe accepts `amount` values in lowest currency values, in this case 100 pence. Then you're attempting to transfer £88 GBP to your connected account where you only have £1 available.

You should revisit your `$splitAmount` logic, as it is always going to amount to `88` regardless of how much you charge your customer.

Answer (score 0):

payable Amount always be greater than transfer amount, [Read More](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers#grouping-transactions-charges) 
changed payable amount. so $payable is greater amount than splitAmount always.

```
     $payable=100*100;  

      $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
            "amount" => $payable, // $100.00 this time
            "currency" => 'GBP',
            "customer" => $stripeDetails['stripe_customer_id']
      ));

      //charge working fine (In Dashboard currency converted GBP to UD)
           //Can only transfer up to the platform’s available account balance (with an exception when using source_transaction),before check it

       $balance = \Stripe\Balance::retrieve(
             ["stripe_account" => CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID]
       );


      $splitAmount = 100 * 2 / 100;
      $splitAmount = 90 - $splitAmount;

      $transfer = \Stripe\Transfer::create(array(
          'amount' => $splitAmount * 100,
          'currency' => 'GBP',
          'destination' => $storeData['stripe_account_id']
      ));
```

Comment: OP isn't using `$payableAmount`. It's also worth adding more explanation in your answer rather than simply saying "read this link" which could be removed or changed any time.

Comment: I tried to give static amount that also not working.. $payableAmount  = 10000 * 100 and transfer amount also i given 10000 * 100

Comment: check, pls, balance of customer account available more than transfer amount

Comment: Admin account Balance : $9,544.98 , Transfer account balance : $2,714.98.. But  itshown the admin account and customer account USD currency. is it any problem? If it is problem how can i change the currency manually in stripe account